# Pre Animation before starting an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-animation

I would like to have some pre-animation before starting My android app. Let me tell me you how am i doing it right now.

I am having another activity which has an ImageView , i open that activity in the background transparent mode and have a delay of 2seconds and then my homescreen is opened.
Now in this concept the problem is that when i press back button at the homescreen, i am jumped to that animation and so i have to press back again.

Now i would like to add animation like we see in the facebook app. I want that first an imageview should appear , then it sould move upwards and then 2 textviews should appear with the dissolve effect. Can anybody tell me how would i make it ?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the back button with the `onBackPressed()` function?

Comment: Yeah i have tried using that. I jumped to the homescreen using a new intent in onBackPressed(). But the problem is that when i next time start the activity, it automatically opens the second activity because it is still on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

make a frame layout for ur activity like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/andro"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
<LinearLayout>
//Other Component Activity
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

then in Activity onCreate method make other component Invisible
using method setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
and after 2 seconds make your code component visible by using method setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and make visibility of your ImageView invisible. in this way when you press back button in no animation you will see and you will get what you need.

Comment: Thankyou. I perhaps got it. And can you please tell how can i get to the second thing. i.e. if a want to move that image from bottom to center. ?